# Need help in converting this code to functional hooks from class component (React)

Tags: reactjs

Currently using TypeScript on my project with React version 16.13.1.

Trying to get the the Autocomplete function working from this [@react-google-maps/api](https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api) but the examples are in class component and i'm using functional hooks.

Any idea whats wrong with my code? Here's an example i got from the library.

Code example from this [library](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#autocomplete)

```
class MyMapWithAutocomplete extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.autocomplete = null

    this.onLoad = this.onLoad.bind(this)
    this.onPlaceChanged = this.onPlaceChanged.bind(this)
  }

  onLoad (autocomplete) {
    console.log('autocomplete: ', autocomplete)

    this.autocomplete = autocomplete
  }

  onPlaceChanged () {
    if (this.autocomplete !== null) {
      console.log(this.autocomplete.getPlace())
    } else {
      console.log('Autocomplete is not loaded yet!')
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ScriptLoaded>
        <GoogleMap
          id="searchbox-example"
          mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
          zoom={2.5}
          center={center}
        >
          <Autocomplete
            onLoad={this.onLoad}
            onPlaceChanged={this.onPlaceChanged}
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Customized your placeholder"
            />
          </Autocomplete>
        </GoogleMap>
      </ScriptLoaded>
    )
  }
}
```

what i have currently

```
function GoogleMaps({ data = [], center, withAutocomplete = false }: MapProps) {
  const [setAutocomplete, autocomplete] = useState() as any
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: 'xxx',
    libraries: ['places']
  })
  const onLoad = useCallback((props) => {
    setAutocomplete(props)
  }, [])

  const onPlaceChanged = () => {
    console.log('place', onLoad)
    if (autocomplete !== null) {
      console.log('test', autocomplete.getPlace())
    }
  }

  const renderMap = () => {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        options={{
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false
        }}
        mapContainerStyle={{ height: '600px' }}
        center={center}
        zoom={12}>
        {data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((d, idx) => {
            const position = { lat: d.lat, lng: d.lng }
            return <Marker position={position} key={`marker-${idx}`} />
          })}
        {withAutocomplete && (
          <Autocomplete onLoad={onLoad} onPlaceChanged={onPlaceChanged}>
            <TextField variant="outlined" />
          </Autocomplete>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    )
  }

  if (loadError) {
    return <div>Map cannot be loaded right now, sorry.</div>
  }

  return isLoaded ? renderMap() : <CircularProgress />
}
```

i got an error when running this. **TypeError: setAutocomplete is not a function**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the array items in the `useState` call backwards:

`const [setAutocomplete, autocomplete] = useState() as any`

You want this:

`const [autocomplete, setAutocomplete] = useState() as any`

The first item in the array is the variable that holds the state value, the second is the function that React uses to maintain it.  In your current code, the `setAutoComplete` is not a function, but `autoComplete` is.

Comment: Probably best to take out `as any` as well - might help catch this kind of error. You can properly type `useState` like this: `useState<string>('initial val')` or whatever type the state is.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't disagree with that at all

Comment: omg, wtf is wrong with me. lmao i didnt even think of that for a second. oh god. that settles it.

and yeah i added  **as any** just for testing purpose. i will add the appropriate type later on